# javascript checkbox (click image - checks box) help w/php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following, I would like to add a feature that will allow me to click the image displayed and checkbox above becomes checked, is it possible?  Seems lines 29-32.  I found an example, but didn't work for me.

thanks

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is a simple PHP script to delete select images.</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['image_list'])) {
            foreach ($_POST['image_list'] as $imagename) {
                if (file_exists($imagename)) {
                    unlink($imagename);    
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
    <form action="images_view.php" method="POST">
        <p>Please select multiple images you want to remove. Please note that the selected images will be removed from server as well.</p>
        <?php
            $files = glob("videos/THUMBNAILS/*.*");
            for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
            {
                $image = $files[$i];
                $supported_file = array(
                    'jpg',
                );


                $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="image_list[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="'.$image.'" />';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="image_list[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="'.$image.'" />';
                    echo basename($image)."<br />"; // show only image name if you want to show full path then use this code // echo $image."<br />";
                    echo '<img src="'.$image .'" style="max-width: calc(100% - 20px); alt="Random image" />'."<br /><br />";
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" style="width:300px;height:60px;margin-left:20px;" value="Delete" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap the checkbox input and the image by a label:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="image_list[<?php echo $imageId; ?>]" />
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ez8pDFoxU2ZqDmyfeIjIba6dWisd8MY_6choHhZNpO0WwLhICu0v0s5eV2WHOhuhKw=w170" />
</label>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hbvnygsb/1/)

In backend you can simply do a foreach and delete the according images:

```
foreach (array_keys($_POST['image_list']) as $imageId) {
    // delete image by id.
}
```

Comment: The following code is working when I click the image the checkbox is selected, however the "delete" function is now not working...